# How to get gitolite / gitweb working together?

Tags: gitolite, gitweb

I have gitweb and gitolite installed. I can configure a repo for gitweb access and it appears in the "projects.list" file but the repo is not listed by gitweb in the browser.

I've been searching and searching but can't find what I am missing to make this work.

My gitweb.conf contains

```
$git_temp = "/tmp";

# The directories where your projects are. Must not end with a slash.
$projectroot = "/srv/git/repositories"; 
$projects_list = "/srv/git/projects.list";
```

My .gitolite.rc contains

```
$PROJECTS_LIST = $ENV{HOME} . "/projects.list";
```

I've checked and the projects.list file goes get updates as per changes to the gitlite config once that is pushed back to the repo. So I think it's just gitweb not seeing the list and acting on it, but I can't figure out know why.

I just get the gitweb page with "404 - No projects found" where the project list should be.

UPDATE:

I found that in my case the problem was caused by incorrect Apache config. I had followed http://git@boron/testing.git. I had the following in my VirtualHost:

```
# Make sure we can execute gitweb okay
<Directory "/srv/http/gitweb">
        Options ExecCGI
        AllowOverride None
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This executed gitweb.cgi directly, as the httpd user and without any environment settings. I replaced this block with an explicit call to my suexec wrapper:

```
# Call GitoWeb cgi via suexec wrapper for relevant URLs
ScriptAliasMatch "^/$" /srv/http/git-suexec/gitweb.cgi.suexec-wrapper
```

And that fixed my problem.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the right httpd.conf. I believe it to be a bit more complete than yours.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP mentions in the comment, you need to make sure your VirtulaHost in the Apache config calls gitweb.cgi with the right parameters/environment variables:

Here is my `httpd.conf` for that service:
Notice how it will avoid `ScriptAliasMatch` and how it does set `GIT_HTTP_BACKEND`.

```
# GitWeb on 8443 # or any port you want
Listen 8443
<VirtualHost hostname>
    ServerName hostname
    ServerAlias short-hostname
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/apache/crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/apache/key"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND /path/to/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend
    DocumentRoot /path/to/gitweb
    Alias /gitweb /path/to/gitweb
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /path/to/gitweb>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        Options ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        AuthName "LDAP authentication for GitWeb repositories"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider myldap companyldap
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative On
        Require valid-user

        AddHandler cgi-script cgi
        DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi

        RewriteEngine Off
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.git/?(\?.*)?$ /gitweb.cgi%{REQUEST_URI} [L,PT]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Original answer:

Here is my `gitweb.conf.pl`:

```
my $gl_home = $ENV{HOME} = "@H@";

# the following variables are needed by gitolite; please edit before using

# this should normally not be anything else
$ENV{GL_RC} = "$gl_home/.gitolite.rc";
# this can have different values depending on how you installed.

# if you used RPM/DEB or "root" methods it **might** be this:
$ENV{GL_BINDIR} = "/usr/local/bin";
# if you used the "non-root" method it **might** be this:
$ENV{GL_BINDIR} = "$gl_home/gitolite/bin";
# If in doubt take a look at ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; at least one of the lines
# might contain something like:
#       command="/home/git/.gitolite/src/gl-auth-command
# and you should use whatever directory the gl-auth-command is in (in this
# example /home/git/.gitolite.src)

# finally the user name
$ENV{GL_USER} = $cgi->remote_user || "gitweb";

# now get gitolite stuff in...
unshift @INC, $ENV{GL_BINDIR};
require gitolite_rc;    gitolite_rc -> import;
require gitolite;       gitolite    -> import;

# set project root etc. absolute paths
$ENV{GL_REPO_BASE_ABS} = ( $REPO_BASE =~ m(^/) ? $REPO_BASE : "$gl_home/$REPO_BASE" );
$projects_list = $projectroot = $ENV{GL_REPO_BASE_ABS};

$export_auth_hook = sub {
    my $repo = shift;
    # gitweb passes us the full repo path; so we strip the beginning
    # and the end, to get the repo name as it is specified in gitolite conf
    return unless $repo =~ s/^\Q$projectroot\E\/?(.+)\.git$/$1/;

    # check for (at least) "R" permission
    my ($perm, $creator) = &repo_rights($repo);
    return ($perm =~ /R/);
};
```

Replace the @H@ by your path where your `.gitolite`, `.gitoliterc`, `repositories`, `project.list` files are.

Note how I defined `$ENV{GL_BINDIR}`: I didn't comment the second definition, because in my case I did a non-root installation, hence the:

```
$ENV{GL_BINDIR} = "$gl_home/gitolite/bin";
```

Make sure to have a `gitweb_config.perl` with:

```
our $home_link_str = "ITSVC projects";
our $site_name = "ITSVC Gitweb";

use lib (".");
require "gitweb.conf.pl";
```

That is what will make the link between `gitweb` and the extra `gitweb.conf.pl` which will call gitolite.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've solved my problem this morning and I've updated my question with what worked for me. I found a few references to gitweb.conf.pl in various posts but I don't seem have this file but I do have gitweb.conf. I don't know if I am still missing something but my setup does seem to work now.