# How to get a fine grained ACL for repositories with smart http access in gitolite?

Tags: git, apache2, gitolite

How can we achieve fine grained ACL with smart http in gitolite?

What this exactly means is: If I restrict certain repos for some users in gitolite using ssh and if I try to clone the restricted repo, gitolite tells:

```
Fatal R any (some_username) is denied. 
Please make sure the repository exists".
```

How to achieve the above mentioned ACL by using smart http?
If possible please specify the setup(apache2) for achieving the same.

Answer (score 0):

**[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/)** is compatible with smart http, as I mentioned [in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9783189/6309) or [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13796467/6309).

All you need to do is set [those 4 lines](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/3fb31b840b6d03e28125ffccb69122c07cd63837/apache/env.conf.tpl#L242-L246):

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT @H@/repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME @H@
ScriptAlias /hgit/ /path/to/gitolite/sbin/gitolite-shell/
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "/path/to/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"
```

That way, any [url with a path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) starting with **`/hgit`** will query gitolite first (through its [`src/gitolite-shell`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gitolite-shell) perl script)

```
git clone http://myserver/hgit/myrepo.git
```

You need to couple that with a way [to authenticate yourself](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) through one of the [authentication basic provider](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html#authbasicprovider) (file, ldap, dbm, ...)
In [my httpd.conf, I use LDAP](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/3fb31b840b6d03e28125ffccb69122c07cd63837/apache/env.conf.tpl#L256-L268).

```
    AuthName "LDAP authentication for ITSVC Smart HTTP Git repositories"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPBindDN "@LDAP_BINDDN@"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword @LDAP_PASSWORD@
    AuthLDAPURL @LDAP_URL@
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
```

You would replace the placeholder string `@xxx@` by [their actual values](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/3fb31b840b6d03e28125ffccb69122c07cd63837/.ldap.example#L1-L3).

Comment: I tried with the above mentioned code. But still i couldn't find the answer.  Can you please post the steps(code) in a sequential  way such that i will get a clear understanding of which step to execute first and which one to do last. I read so many documents about "smart-http" implementation and it's actually very confusing and everybody implemented the same topic in multiple ways which seems very complicated for a starter like me. Please help me solve this issue.